# Accessing TextField from Another QML File

Tags: qt, qml

I have two .qml files:

**CustomText.qml**:

```
Item 
{
    TextField
    {
        id: t1
        placeholderText: qsTr("Enter name")
    }
}
```

**main.qml**:

```
Window 
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    CustomText {width: 200; height: 200}

    Rectangle
    {
        id: r1      
        border.color: "black"
        width: 200
        height: 200
        x: 200
        y: 200
        Text 
        {
            text: t1.text
        }
    }
}
```

This code is not working, because the id is not known. How can I access the text from the `TextField` in `main.qml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can accomplish this, namely

1. Aliasing `t1.text`, Binding `customText.text`, *or*
2. Aliasing `t1`, Binding `customText.t1.text`

Note that in both methods, we'll need to provide an `id` to your instance of `CustomText` so that we can refer to it. In both methods, we'll also make use of [`property aliases`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#property-aliases). These allow you to expose certain properties of your `CustomText`.

#### Alias `t1.text`, Bind `customText.text`

```
// CustomText.qml
Item 
{
    property alias text: t1.text    // set a property alias

    TextField
    {
        id: t1
        placeholderText: qsTr("Enter name")
    }
}

// Main.qml
Window 
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    CustomText { id: customText; width: 200; height: 200 }   // provide an id for reference    

    Rectangle
    {
        id: r1      
        border.color: "black"
        width: 200
        height: 200
        x: 200
        y: 200
        Text 
        {
            text: customText.text      // bind the text property
        }
    }
}
```

#### Alias `t1`, Bind `customText.t1.text`

```
// CustomText.qml
Item 
{
    property alias t1: t1      // set a property alias

    TextField
    {
        id: t1
        placeholderText: qsTr("Enter name")
    }
}

// Main.qml
Window 
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    CustomText { id: customText; width: 200; height: 200 }    // provide an id for reference    

    Rectangle
    {
        id: r1      
        border.color: "black"
        width: 200
        height: 200
        x: 200
        y: 200
        Text 
        {
            text: customText.t1.text    // bind the property
        }
    }
}
```

If you're only needing to use the text from the `TextField` and nothing else, I would recommend using the first method, since you still keep the rest of `t1` encapsulated (one might also say a "*private*" variable).

Generally, *never* use the second method unless you're having to modify the *entire* `t1` object outside the file. (There may be some exceptions, but such a pattern tends to suggest a flaw in the design pattern and require refactoring.) Stick with the first method. If you're finding yourself having to reference/modify other properties of the `TextField` (the `placeholderText`, `font`, etc), you should alias and expose those properties as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the solution i searched for.