# Multiple QML files with Items ids called in them (causing referenceError)

Tags: qt, qml

I'm relatively new to Qt, currently help in maintaining and scaling a Qt project. Instead of having all the UI in 1 qml file, I organized them that each page/window is in separate qml file (e.g. HomePage.qml, ConnectionStatusPage.qml).

Since some Item ids were called and used in the (previous) main UI code in other items, now I have referenceError appearing from the other files. The project is being scaled and getting more complex, many new UIs will be created and Items defined is one file will be used in others too.

1. How can I reference the Items inside other file properly without
   errors
2. What's the appropriate way to structure the code UI files for a
   scalable and reusable manner (I'm sure there are proper ways)

code example:

HomePage.qml

```
// previous code ...
Item {
    id:websocket
    void func_1():
        ...
    }
```

ConnectionStatusPage.qml

```
// Label item
Label {
    id: labelFirst
    text: websocket.status == someStatus ? option_1 : option_2
    }
```

Running this gives me error such as:

> ReferenceError: websocket is not defined

Comment: Typo? In HomePage.qml, your id is `webSocket`, but in the other page you look for `websocket`. They are case-sensitive.

Comment: was typo in this specific question, edited, thanks for mentioning it. But the code has no typos.

Comment: For your question #1, there are lots of ways to do it, depending on how your app is structured. A minimal, reproducible example might be helpful to give a more specific answer. For #2, this question is very broad and probably opinion-based.

Comment: @AnasAG please provide a [mre]

Comment: For the first question, I found a solution in this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/55314749/11561028

Comment: For second question, as @JarMan said, its a broad topic. I was searching for leads and main topics to get familiar with it. For the moment, I'll keep doing some research to understand how the code structure could be made for scalable manner.

Answer (score 0):

What I find works well is to use QtObject singletons. More info about QtObject here:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qtobject.html

They are the most basic, non-visual containers in QML.

Info about singletons here:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html

This allows you to import references to persistent singleton objects outside of your UI into any of your UI QML files. Trying to put stateful non-UI functionality into UI QML is (as you discovered) difficult to manage because of both the dynamic creation and destruction of UI plus the difficulty in maintaining references to it from other parts of your UI.

So, I'd move your websocket functionality to a new QtObject singleton that's imported into both HomePage and ConnectionStatusPage.

Comment: I'll check QtObject singletons in more detail to see if it's the right approach, thanks for mentioning it.