# Update Text inside loaded qml file

Tags: qt, properties, qml, pyside

We are having an `ApplicationWindow` based `main.qml` which is connected to our python backend via  QmlElement `Bridge`. We have a view `Slot-methods` which directly return values to the qml frontend to change textfields which are children of the `ApplicationWindow` like the following:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainFrame
    width: 1280
    height: 720
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Test")

    StackView {
        id: stack
        initialItem: loginFrame
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Bridge {
        id: bridge
    }

    Component{
        id: loginFrame

        ColumnLayout {
            anchors.margins: 3
            spacing: 3
            Layout.columnSpan: 1
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter

            Text {
                id: title
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                font.pointSize: 16
                text: "Login Screen"
                Layout.preferredHeight: 100

            }
            Button {
                id: loginButton
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                text: "login"
                highlighted: true
                Material.accent: Material.Red
                onClicked: {
                    title.text = bridge.login(username.text, password.text)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To reduce the size of our `main.qml` we decided to load the other Layouts, Components etc from different files with

```
Loader {
    id: otherLoader
    source: "other.qml"
}
```

How to access the `Text` Object inside of `other.qml` to update the `text` property from `main.qml` because the value is provided by the `Bridge`?

I already tried [Accessing TextField from Another QML File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55314749/accessing-textfield-from-another-qml-file) but this hasn't worked.

Comment: Why don't you create components out of the other layouts instead of using Loaders? This way you can use the alias approach you've linked in your port.

Comment: Our approach with the loaders, was simply to divide one big qml file in multiple. Maybe we misunderstood something in this approach. Could you specify how to achieve what you say about creating components out of the other layouts?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-tutorial2.html Create a LayoutA.qml and LayoutB.qml, implement the Layouts in there, forward the necessary properties via `alias` or `binding` and instantiate them like `LayoutA {}` and `LayoutB {}` in the main.qml

Comment: Yes you were right, about the approach with components. Actually I can't remember why we used the Loader in the first place. Maybe because it would lead to better performance because those layouts are used in a stacklayout. But since we didn'T recognized any performance issues yet and are far away from optimizing our tool, the direct access to the component will satisfy for the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Loader` creates items in not the same context as the statically create item use so cannot access the loaded item. You have several ways to access such an item.

The first and the most correct way is to use a declarative style:

```js
Item {
    id: container
    anchors.fill: parent
    property string someText: "press again"
    Loader {
        id: loader
        active: false
        sourceComponent: Text {
            id: txt
            text: container.someText
        }
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            if(loader.active)
                container.someText = "some text"
            else
                loader.active = true
        }
    }
}
```

You can create a binding in a `Javascript` code whenever you want:

```js
    Loader {
        id: loader
        active: false
        sourceComponent: Text {
            id: txt
            Component.onCompleted: {
                txt.text = Qt.binding(function() { return container.someText; })
            }
        }
    }
```

Another option is using [Loader.item](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-loader.html#item-prop) property:

```js
Item {
    id: container
    anchors.fill: parent
    property string someText: "some text"
    Loader {
        id: loader
        active: false
        sourceComponent: Text {
            id: txt
            text: "press again"
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            if(loader.active)
                loader.item.text = "some text"
            else
                loader.active = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to "import" files in another way instead of the loader, to create the context?

Comment: I guess no, if you create items dynamically. But that's is the meaning of the declarative approach, you don't say ' how to do' but instead 'what you want to see'. You cannot access the item, at least access in some common way but item can access the top-level elements so let him do the work.

Comment: Just to bring the flow of thought into context: Meanwhile I've learned a lot about `property` and `property alias` in qml. This was necessary knowledge for me to understand this answer.